# Can't import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

Tags: scala, reflection

I'd like to play around with reflection in scala (2.10.2) by following the example in 
[this tutorial](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html). things work fine when I start the sbt (version 0.13) and import
scala.refelct.runtime.universe._

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._                                                                                                                                       │~                                                                                                                                                                                   
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
```

but when I try to put the sample code to an object like

```
object ReflectExample {
   import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
   /*
    the rest of the Example
   */
}
```

and compile the code by sbt compile I see the following error message like:

```
[error]  object runtime is not a member of package reflect                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[error]     import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
```

Comment: Is scala-reflect.jar in your library ?

Answer (score 23):

As explained in [sbt's documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Macro-Projects.html), you need to add this line to the `libraryDependencies` field of your project in `build.sbt`:

`"org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value`

Answer (score 13):

You may want to try adding dependency to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect

Comment: worked for me, just added "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.10.0"

Comment: I got the same issue but the solution is not working a I need to run with Scala 2.12.0 (to run Apache Spark).  However, I'm getting: /var/folders/g8/xtvb9ft52hgfw08sfxhjkxh5x3qbdd/T/sbt_6999744/scala/ZincCompat.scala:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : pf.type (with underlying type scala.ZincCompat.PlainNioFile)
 required: ?{def getClass: ?}
    val f = pf.getClass.getDeclaredField("nioPath") // it's not val'd in 2.12 :-/

Comment: @RonyArmon were you able to solve the issue?