# Scala 2.12: Compile error - type PlainNioFile is not a member of package scala.reflect.io

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm trying to compile my spark scala application and getting below error. Same code was working fine with scala 2.11 version.

I did look at this solution and tried adding scala-reflect as the dependency but still getting the same error. I do see scala-reflect is added as dependency

[Can't import scala.reflect.runtime.universe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189608/cant-import-scala-reflect-runtime-universe/25191687)

Scala version 2.12.10

```
[info] Non-compiled module 'compiler-bridge_2.12' for Scala 2.12.0. Compiling...
/var/folders/92/9c7h444d28x8rtcm91n0r7bc0000gq/T/sbt_97534c54/scala/ZincCompat.scala:19: error: type PlainNioFile is not a member of package scala.reflect.io
  type PlainNioFile = scala.reflect.io.PlainNioFile
                                       ^
/var/folders/92/9c7h444d28x8rtcm91n0r7bc0000gq/T/sbt_97534c54/scala/ZincCompat.scala:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : pf.type (with underlying type scala.ZincCompat.PlainNioFile)
 required: ?{def getClass: ?}
    val f = pf.getClass.getDeclaredField("nioPath") // it's not val'd in 2.12 :-/
two errors found
[info] Attempting to fetch org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.6.0.
[warn] Unrecognized repository Scala Plugin Bundled Repository, ignoring it
[warn] Unrecognized repository Scala Plugin Bundled Repository, ignoring it
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Error compiling the sbt component 'compiler-bridge_2.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is build-time error, not compile-time error, so there is no sense to add `scala-reflect` to `build.sbt`. It's not your code that needs `scala-reflect` but sbt.

The thing is in binary incompatibility between sbt zinc `compiler-bridge` and `scala-reflect`.

`scala.reflect.io.PlainNioFile` appeared in `scala-reflect` 2.12.1

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0/src/reflect/scala/reflect/io/PlainFile.scala

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/reflect/scala/reflect/io/PlainFile.scala#L94

`type PlainNioFile = scala.reflect.io.PlainNioFile` appeared in `compiler-bridge` 1.4.0

https://github.com/sbt/zinc/blob/v1.4.0/internal/compiler-bridge/src/main/scala-2.12/scala/ZincCompat.scala#L19

https://github.com/sbt/zinc/commit/172d638c28ef46a47d5f2944671103069ef7fa2c

So sbt 1.4.+ is incompatible with Scala 2.12.0-

Try either to upgrade to Scala 2.12.1+ or downgrade to sbt 1.3.13-

> Scala version 2.12.10

As you can see in `Non-compiled module 'compiler-bridge_2.12' for Scala 2.12.0. Compiling...`, somewhere Scala 2.12.0 is used.

---

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12195#issuecomment-713009934

> @som-snytt: sbt compiler bridge has finite backward compatibility.

https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/issues/474

*compiler-bridge_2.12:1.3.0 not compatible with scala-compiler:2.13.1* https://github.com/sbt/zinc/issues/698

[Error compiling the sbt component 'compiler-bridge_2.11'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101210/error-compiling-the-sbt-component-compiler-bridge-2-11)